useQueryClient is not working, query invalidation not refetching the api's its not working, when any action is triggered
import AppTextInput from '@/components/form-fields/AppTextInput';
import Iconify from '@/components/iconify/Iconify';
import AppButton from '@/components/templates/AppButton';
import AppDataGrid from '@/components/templates/AppDataGrid';
import AppLink from '@/components/templates/AppLink';
import AppPersona from '@/components/templates/AppPersona';
import TableSkeleton from '@/components/templates/AppTable/TableSkeleton';
import AppTag from '@/components/templates/AppTag';
import AppTitle from '@/components/templates/AppTitle';
import {
  CACHE_KEY_AVAILABLE_PAYROLL,
  CACHE_KEY_GENERATED_PAYROLL,
  CACHE_KEY_PAYROLL_CYCLE_PAYRUN,
  CACHE_KEY_PAYROLL_STATUS_HEADER,
  CACHE_KEY_POSTED_PAYROLL,
  CACHE_KEY_PROCESSED_PAYROLL,
  PAYROLL_CYCLE_LOCK_ENDPOINT,
  PAYROLL_CYCLE_PAYRUN_ENDPOINT,
  PAYROLL_CYCLE_SIF_ENDPOINT,
  PAYROLL_EMP_BY_STATUS_ENDPOINT,
} from '@/constants/payroll';
import useGetAll from '@/hooks/useGetAll';
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  Divider,
  Grid,
  IconButton,
  Menu,
  MenuItem,
  Paper,
  Stack,
  Step,
  StepButton,
  Stepper,
  Typography,
} from '@mui/material';
import {
  GridColDef,
  GridRenderCellParams,
  GridRowSelectionModel,
} from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import * as React from 'react';
import { useLocation, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import StatusCardList from './status-card-list';
import ProcessPopup, { PAYROLL_UPDATE_PAYLOAD } from './process-popup';
import usePut from '@/hooks/usePut';
import AppDrawer from '@/components/templates/AppDrawer';
import PayView from './payview';
import { useState } from 'react';
import nav from '@/AppLayout/nav';
import APIClient from '@/services/api-client';
import { SearchOutlined } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { useQueryClient } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { PAYROLL } from '../payroll-list';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import useUserStore from '@/store/user.store';

export type PAYROLL_PROCESS =
  | 'AVAILABLE'
  | 'GENERATED'
  | 'PROCESSED'
  | 'POSTED';

interface STEP {
  id: PAYROLL_PROCESS;
  label: string;
}

const steps: STEP[] = [
  // { id: 'AVAILABLE', label: 'Available Payroll' }, //included this line by Priti
  { id: 'AVAILABLE', label: 'Available Employee' },
  { id: 'GENERATED', label: 'Generated Payroll' },
  { id: 'POSTED', label: 'Posted Payroll' },
  { id: 'PROCESSED', label: 'Processed Payroll' },
];

function Payrun() {
  const params = useParams();

  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState<number>(0);
  const [rowSelectionModel, setRowSelectionModel] =
    React.useState<GridRowSelectionModel>([]);
  const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] =
    React.useState<PAYROLL_UPDATE_PAYLOAD>();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [deleteOpen, setDeleteOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const { data, refetch, error, isLoading, isFetching } =
    useGetAll<EMP_PAYROLL_STATUS>(
      PAYROLL_EMP_BY_STATUS_ENDPOINT +
        '?' +
        'payrollCycleId=' +
        params.id +
        '&status=' +
        steps[activeStep].id,
      activeStep === 0
        ? CACHE_KEY_AVAILABLE_PAYROLL
        : activeStep === 1
        ? CACHE_KEY_GENERATED_PAYROLL
        : activeStep === 2
        ? CACHE_KEY_POSTED_PAYROLL
        : CACHE_KEY_PROCESSED_PAYROLL
    );
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isFetching) {
      console.log('Refetching data...');
    }
  }, [isFetching]);
  const handleRowSelection = (rowIds: GridRowSelectionModel) => {
    setRowSelectionModel(rowIds);

    const rows = data && data.filter((d) => rowIds.includes(d.id));

    if (activeStep === 0)
      setSelectedRows({
        payrollCycleId: params.id!,
        employees: rows?.map((r) => r.id),
      });
    else
      setSelectedRows({
        payrollCycleId: params.id!,
        payrollId: rows?.map((r) => r.payrollId),
      });
  };

  const [menuAnchor, setMenuAnchor] = React.useState<HTMLElement | null>(null);

  const handleMenuClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setMenuAnchor(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleMenuClose = () => {
    setMenuAnchor(null);
  };
  const getActionLabel = () => {
    switch (steps[activeStep].id) {
      case 'AVAILABLE':
        return ['Generate Payroll'];
      case 'GENERATED':
        return ['Post Payroll', 'Delete'];
      case 'POSTED':
        return ['Process Payroll', 'Delete'];
      case 'PROCESSED':
        return ['No Actions needed'];
      default:
        return ['Action'];
    }
  };
  const invalidateStatusHeaderQuery = () => {
    queryClient.invalidateQueries(CACHE_KEY_PAYROLL_STATUS_HEADER);
  };
  // const invalidatePayrollQueries = () => {
  //   queryClient.invalidateQueries(CACHE_KEY_AVAILABLE_PAYROLL);
  //   queryClient.invalidateQueries(CACHE_KEY_GENERATED_PAYROLL);
  //   queryClient.invalidateQueries(CACHE_KEY_POSTED_PAYROLL);
  //   queryClient.invalidateQueries(CACHE_KEY_PROCESSED_PAYROLL);
  // };
  const refetchTableData = () => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient(); // Get the query client instance
    queryClient.invalidateQueries(CACHE_KEY_PAYROLL_CYCLE_PAYRUN);
    // invalidatePayrollQueries();
    invalidateStatusHeaderQuery();
    console.log('Table data refetched');
    queryClient.invalidateQueries([
      CACHE_KEY_PAYROLL_CYCLE_PAYRUN,
      CACHE_KEY_AVAILABLE_PAYROLL,
      CACHE_KEY_GENERATED_PAYROLL,
      CACHE_KEY_POSTED_PAYROLL,
      CACHE_KEY_PROCESSED_PAYROLL,
      CACHE_KEY_PAYROLL_STATUS_HEADER,
    ]); // Refetch all invalidated queries
  };

  const user = useUserStore((state) => state.user);
  const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    {
      field: 'firstName',
      minWidth: 200,
      flex: 1,
      headerName: 'Employee Name',
      renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => {
        const { value, row }: { value?: string; row: any } = params;
        return (
          <AppPersona
            profile={{
              maintext: value + ' ' + row.lastName,
              subtext: '#' + row.empCode,
            }}
          />
        );
      },
    },
    {
      field: 'departmentId',
      minWidth: 200,
      flex: 1,
      headerName: 'Department & Division',
      renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => {
        const { value, row }: { value?: string; row: any } = params;
        return (
          <Box>
            <Typography
              variant='body2'
              fontWeight={'fontWeightMedium'}
              sx={{ color: 'text.primary' }}
            >
              {value!}
            </Typography>
            <Typography
              variant='caption'
              sx={{ color: 'text.secondary' }}
              fontWeight='fontWeightMedium'
            >
              {row.divisionId!}
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        );
        // return <AppTitle title={value!} subtitle={row.division!} />;
      },
    },
    // {
    //   field: 'salary',
    //   minWidth: 100,
    //   width: 150,
    //   headerName: 'Salary',
    //   renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => {
    //     return (
    //       <Typography variant='body2' fontWeight='fontWeightMedium'>
    //         INR. {params.value}
    //       </Typography>
    //     );
    //   },
    // },
    {
      field: 'status',
      minWidth: 80,
      width: 150,
      headerName: 'Status',
      renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => {
        const val = params?.value?.toUpperCase() || 'NA'!;
        return (
          <AppTag
            variant={
              val === 'GENERATED'
                ? 'ACTIVE'
                : val === 'POSTED'
                ? 'INACTIVE'
                : ''
            }
            text={val}
          />
        );
      },
    },
    {
      field: 'action',
      flex: 1,
      headerAlign: 'center',
      align: 'center',
      headerName: 'Action',
      renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => {
        const { row }: { row: any } = params;
        return (
          <Stack
            sx={{ width: '70px' }}
            direction='row'
            alignItems='center'
            justifyContent='space-between'
          >
            <AppButton
              sx={{
                color: 'primary.main',
                fontWeight: 600,
                textDecoration: 'none',
                padding: '4px 10px',
                display: 'inline-flex',
                alignItems: 'center',
              }}
              variant='text'
              onClick={() => handleOpenDrawer(row?.payrollId)}
            >
              View
            </AppButton>
            {/* <Iconify icon='ic:sharp-more-vert' width={22} /> */}
            {/* <IconButton onClick={handleMenuClick}>
              <Iconify icon='ic:sharp-more-vert' width={18} />
            </IconButton>
            <Menu
              anchorEl={menuAnchor}
              open={Boolean(menuAnchor)}
              onClose={handleMenuClose}
            >
              {getActionLabel().map((label, index) => (
                <MenuItem
                  key={index}
                  onClick={() => handleMenuItemClick(label)}
                >
                  {label}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu> */}
          </Stack>
        );
      },
    },
  ];
  const [viewTitle, setViewTitle] = useState('');
  const [isDrawerOpen, setIsDrawerOpen] = useState<string>(''); // New state to track drawer open/close

  const { id } = useParams();
  // Function to open the drawer
  const handleOpenDrawer = (id: string) => {
    setIsDrawerOpen(id);
  };

  // Function to close the drawer
  const handleCloseDrawer = () => {
    setIsDrawerOpen('');
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      setIsDrawerOpen('');
    }
  }, [id]);

  const downloadSif = () => {
    const apiClient = new APIClient(PAYROLL_CYCLE_SIF_ENDPOINT(params.id!));
    apiClient
      .get()
      .then((response) => response.blob())
      .then((blob) => {
        const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = fileURL;

        const dt = new Date();
        const yr = dt.getFullYear().toString().slice(-2);
        const mn = (dt.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
        const dd = dt.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
        const hr = dt.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
        const min = dt.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
        const sec = dt.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');
        link.download = `${'0000001145097'}${yr}${mn}${dd}${hr}${min}${sec}.txt`;

        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);

        toast.success('SIF file downloaded successfully!');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error downloading SIF file:', error);
        if (
          error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.validations &&
          error.response.data.validations[0]
        ) {
          toast.error(error.response.data.validations[0].message);
        } else {
          toast.error('An error occurred while downloading the SIF file.');
        }
      });
  };

  const lockPayroll = (payrollCycleId: string) => {
    const service = new APIClient(PAYROLL_CYCLE_LOCK_ENDPOINT + params.id);
    service
      .put({ id: payrollCycleId })
      .then((data) => {
        // Invalidate relevant queries
        queryClient.invalidateQueries(CACHE_KEY_PAYROLL_CYCLE_PAYRUN);
        toast.success('Payroll locked !');
        refetchTableData();
        refetch();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle error
        console.error('Error making employee inactive:', error);
        toast.error('Failed to lock payroll');
      });
  };
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  // const onEdit = (editData: PAYROLL) => {
  //   queryClient.setQueryData<PAYROLL>(CACHE_KEY_PAYROLL_CYCLE_PAYRUN, editData);
  // };
  const location = useLocation();

  const { state } = location;
  console.log(state, 'state');
  return (
    <Paper
      sx={{
        border: '1px solid',
        borderColor: 'background.neutral',
        backgroundColor: 'background.paper',
        borderRadius: 2.5,
        m: 4,
        overflow: 'auto',
      }}
    >
      <Grid container direction='row' sx={{ height: '100%' }}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Stack sx={{ height: '100%' }} divider={<Divider />}>
            <Stack
              sx={{ px: 2.5, pt: 2.5, pb: 4 }}
              direction='row'
              justifyContent='space-between'
            >
              <AppTitle
                title={'Payroll Cycle Details  '}
                subtitle={`${state?.dateFrom} - ${state?.dateTo}`}
              />

              <Button
                variant='outlined'
                onClick={() => {
                  if (params.id) {
                    lockPayroll(params.id);
                  } else {
                    console.error('PayrollCycleId is undefined');
                    toast.error(
                      'Failed to lock payroll: PayrollCycleId is undefined'
                    );
                  }
                }}
              >
                <Iconify icon='ic:round-lock' width={18} />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;Lock Payroll
              </Button>
            </Stack>
            <Box>
              <StatusCardList />
              <Stepper sx={{ pt: 2, px: 1 }} nonLinear activeStep={activeStep}>
                {steps.map((step, index) => (
                  <Step key={step.label}>
                    <StepButton onClick={() => setActiveStep(index)}>
                      {step.label}
                    </StepButton>
                  </Step>
                ))}
              </Stepper>
              <Box sx={{ mt: 5 }}>
                <Stack
                  px={2}
                  direction='row'
                  justifyContent='space-between'
                  alignItems='center'
                >
                  <AppTitle title={'List of Payrolls'} />
                  <Stack direction='row' spacing={2} sx={{ width: '50%' }}>
                    <AppTextInput
                      startIcon={<SearchOutlined />}
                      placeholder='Search by Request Id, Emp no'
                    />
                    <IconButton onClick={() => {}}>
                      <Iconify icon='mdi:filter-outline' width={18} />
                    </IconButton>
                    {activeStep !== 3 && (
                      <AppButton
                        onClick={() => {
                          setOpen(true); // Open the dialog or popup for the action
                          // Assuming the action is completed successfully and you want to update the table
                          // Call refetch to fetch the latest data from the API
                          refetchTableData();

                          refetch();
                          console.log('Refetching data...');
                        }}
                        variant='contained'
                        disabled={!rowSelectionModel.length}
                        disableRipple
                      >
                        {activeStep === 0
                          ? 'Generate '
                          : activeStep === 1
                          ? 'Post '
                          : 'Process '}
                        Payroll
                      </AppButton>
                    )}
                    {activeStep === 3 && (
                      <Button
                        variant='text'
                        onClick={downloadSif}
                        startIcon={
                          <Iconify
                            icon='ic:baseline-cloud-download'
                            width={16}
                          />
                        }
                      >
                        SIF Download
                      </Button>
                    )}

                    {activeStep === 1 && (
                      <Button
                        variant='text'
                        disabled={!rowSelectionModel.length}
                        startIcon={<Iconify icon='ic:delete' width={16} />}
                        onClick={() => {
                          setDeleteOpen(true);
                        }}
                      >
                        Delete
                      </Button>
                    )}
                  </Stack>
                </Stack>
                <Box sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
                  {data && !isLoading ? (
                    <AppDataGrid
                      columns={columns}
                      rows={data}
                      rowHeight={75}
                      getRowId={(row: EMP_PAYROLL_STATUS) => row.id}
                      checkboxSelection={activeStep !== 3}
                      onRowSelectionModelChange={(
                        newRowSelectionModel: GridRowSelectionModel
                      ) => {
                        handleRowSelection(newRowSelectionModel);
                      }}
                      rowSelectionModel={rowSelectionModel}
                    />
                  ) : (
                    <TableSkeleton columns={columns} />
                  )}
                </Box>
              </Box>
            </Box>
          </Stack>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      {selectedRows && (
        <>
          <ProcessPopup
            data={selectedRows}
            process={steps[activeStep].id}
            open={open}
            setOpen={setOpen}
            refetchTableData={refetchTableData}
          />
          {activeStep == 1 && (
            <ProcessPopup
              data={selectedRows}
              process={'DELETE'}
              open={deleteOpen}
              setOpen={setDeleteOpen}
              refetchTableData={refetchTableData}
            />
          )}
        </>
      )}

      <AppDrawer
        header={viewTitle || 'View Leave'}
        open={!!isDrawerOpen} // Use the state to control drawer open/close
        setOpen={handleCloseDrawer} // Pass the close function to the AppDrawer
      >
        {isDrawerOpen && <PayView setTitle={setViewTitle} id={isDrawerOpen!} />}
      </AppDrawer>
    </Paper>
  );
}

export default React.memo(Payrun);

interface EMP_PAYROLL_STATUS {
  id: string;
  payrollId: string;
  payrollCycleId: string;
  title: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  empCode: string;
  departmentId: string;
  divisionId: string;
  salary: number;
  status: PAYROLL_PROCESS;
  payMode: string;
}


here im invalidating all the api by query.invalidators but its not working its not refetching the api
hence
CACHE_KEY_PAYROLL_CYCLE_PAYRUN it has these values which is gets from api and its already set in a constant file
export const CACHE_KEY_PAYROLL_CYCLE_PAYRUN = [
'payroll',
'cycle',
'payrun',
'list',
];
import * as React from 'react';
// @mui
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
//
import AppThemeProvider from '@/theme';
import { Box } from '@mui/material';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from '@tanstack/react-query-devtools';
import { Navigate, Outlet, useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './header';
import Nav from './nav';
import AppMain from './app-main';
import useUserStore from '@/store/user.store';
import useConfigStore from '@/store/config.store';

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

const APP_BAR_MOBILE = 64;
const APP_BAR_DESKTOP = 72;

let tempNavWidthFix = 88;

const StyledRoot = styled('div')({
  display: 'flex',
  minHeight: '100%',
  overflow: 'hidden',
});

const Main = styled('main', {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'navWidth',
  // name: 'Main',
  // slot: 'Root',
  // // We are specifying here how the styleOverrides are being applied based on props
  // overridesResolver: (props, styles) => [
  //   styles.root,
  //   { width: `calc(100vw - ${props.navWidth}px)` },
  // ],
})(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  flexGrow: 1,
  overflow: 'visible',
  minHeight: '100%',
  marginTop: APP_BAR_MOBILE,
  width: '100vw',
  height: '100%',
  [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    // padding: '100px 16px',
    width: `calc(100vw - ${tempNavWidthFix}px)`, //need to get the navWidth dynamically using shouldForwardProp
    // width: `calc(100vw - ${navWidth}px)`, //need to get the navWidth dynamically using shouldForwardProp
    height: '100%',
    marginTop: APP_BAR_DESKTOP,
    // paddingLeft: theme.spacing(2),
    // paddingRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}));

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
type IProps = {
  protected?: boolean;
};
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: true, // default: true
      staleTime: 100,
    },
  },
});

const AppLayout = (props: IProps) => {
  const user = useUserStore((state) => state.user);

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [navWidth, setNavWidth] = React.useState(88);
  const [icon, setIcon] = React.useState('ic:baseline-chevron-right');
  const [toggleDrawer, settoggleDrawer] = React.useState(true);
  const clearConfigs = useConfigStore((state) => state.clearConfigs);
  const location = useLocation();
  const nav = useNavigate();
  const handleToggleDrawer = () => {
    settoggleDrawer(!toggleDrawer);
    setNavWidth(toggleDrawer ? 280 : 88);
    tempNavWidthFix = toggleDrawer ? 280 : 88;
    setIcon(
      toggleDrawer ? 'ic:baseline-chevron-left' : 'ic:baseline-chevron-right'
    );
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (user && location.pathname == '/') {
      nav('/dashboard');
    }
  }, [user, location.pathname]);
  if (props.protected && !user) {
    return <Navigate to='/auth/login' replace />;
  }

  return (
    <AppThemeProvider>
      <StyledRoot>
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          {props.protected && (
            <Header onOpenNav={() => setOpen(true)} navWidth={navWidth} />
          )}
          <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', minHeight: '100%' }}>
            {props.protected && (
              <Nav
                handleToggleDrawer={handleToggleDrawer}
                toggleDrawer={toggleDrawer}
                navWidth={navWidth}
                icon={icon}
                openNav={open}
                onCloseNav={() => setOpen(false)}
              />
            )}

            <Main
              sx={{
                backgroundColor: 'background.default',
              }}
            >
              <AppMain>
                <Outlet />
              </AppMain>
              <ReactQueryDevtools />
            </Main>
          </Box>
        </QueryClientProvider>
      </StyledRoot>
    </AppThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default AppLayout;


this is the index where the query client is associated please give me the solution how to get the api to refetch when the any of the action is triggered

 const refetchTableData = () => {
queryClient.invalidateQueries(CACHE_KEY_PAYROLL_CYCLE_PAYRUN);
invalidateStatusHeaderQuery();
console.log('Table data refetched');

// Define an object mapping each step to its cache key
const stepCacheKeys = {
  AVAILABLE: CACHE_KEY_AVAILABLE_PAYROLL,
  GENERATED: CACHE_KEY_GENERATED_PAYROLL,
  POSTED: CACHE_KEY_POSTED_PAYROLL,
  PROCESSED: CACHE_KEY_PROCESSED_PAYROLL,
};

// Invalidate the query associated with the current step
const currentStepCacheKey = stepCacheKeys[steps[activeStep].id];
if (currentStepCacheKey) {
  queryClient.invalidateQueries(currentStepCacheKey);
}

// Invalidate other relevant queries
queryClient.invalidateQueries([
  CACHE_KEY_PAYROLL_CYCLE_PAYRUN,
  CACHE_KEY_PAYROLL_STATUS_HEADER,
]);

};
when we perform actions such as posting payroll or processing payroll, it will invalidate the queries associated with the current step and move the data to the next step automatically
we can acheive this by only the steps because i already implement the steps
